# Dropping pins on an IOS map with MapKit?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, geolocation, mapkit

I'm trying to learn to use MapKit by creating a sample project; I want to create a map that has all the locations of a particular chain of restaurants with a pin dropped on their coordinate locations (which I have).

The region for this area is Boston, MA and I have a working program of the map with user location shown as a blue dot.

I have been trying to sift through the documentation for MapKit but I can't figure out what I would need to do in order to start the process of placing the pins on all of the store locations.

Comment: edit your question and show your attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "pins" are referred to as Annotations within Swift. It's really easy to add them to a map view, and the default annotation is the pin that you're looking for. Make sure you have an outlet in the body of your view controller:

```
var storeLocationMapView: MKMapView?
```

Then for every location you would like to add, you'll need to make an annotation and add it to the map view. This code assumes you have an array of store locations where each store location is two numbers representing the coordinates of the store.

```
for storeLocation in storeLocations {

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = storeLocation
    storeLocationMapView?.addAnnotation(annotation)

}
```